# Tabulate Google Json response file for directions

Tags: tabulator

I need to tabulate informations from Google JSON file, that is an output of a query to google in order to obtain transit time with and without traffic recorded in a table

I tried to use the ajax loading method as follows (with the correct link instead of "http://www.getmydata.com/now"

```
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    ajaxURL:"http://www.getmydata.com/now", //ajax URL
});
```

I retrieve an error from the tabulator.

Google Json response has this format:

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "Los Cuartos, Naucalpan de Juárez, Méx., Messico" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Città del Messico, Distretto Federale, Messico" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "17,6 km",
                  "value" : 17553
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "38 min",
                  "value" : 2273
               },
               "duration_in_traffic" : {
                  "text" : "31 min",
                  "value" : 1878
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Any hint how to solve??

Comment: Can you please create a JSfiddle and post the link here so that we can really understand the problem Thanks

Comment: Try putting the response into a new varible that is an array e.g. rows =[]; and then set this variable to tabulator as tabledata

Comment: Here it is https://jsfiddle.net/bmwey7g6/5/

Comment: Hello, sorry I meant a 'working' Jsfiddle that shows your problem

Comment: is there a way to add tabulator in jsfiddle?

Comment: you can fork this Jsfiddle (not the best way) but works https://jsfiddle.net/dota2pro/2w8secqy/